# GitHub, how to add store python code coverage report(using coverage.py) in actions and add badge to repo?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, code-coverage, pylint

I've set up coverage.py in my GitHub actions to generate a code coverage report. It displays the report if I go to each action, how do I store the report on my repository and display the code coverage percentage as a badge as well.

This is my build.yml file with the code coverage:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
               
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Python Dependencies
        run: |
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
      - name: Run linter on src directory
        run: |
          pylint --rcfile=pylintrc src
      - name: Run tests and coverage report
        run: |       
          coverage run --data-file tests/.coverage -m pytest -s
          coverage json --data-file tests/.coverage -o buf/tests/coverage.json
          coverage report --data-file tests/.coverage
```

Is it possible for me to add a pylint badge to the repo from the actions as well ?

Comment: Does this question refer to how the report can be saved? If you have a generated report, you can simply push it into the repo with the standard git commands.
Or is it about how the saved report can also be displayed as a badge? For that I would recommend shields.io. You can also specify a JSON link there from which the data is then read.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a blog post detailing a simple way: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202209/making_a_coverage_badge.html